# Windows Server 2016 slow boot (Over 15 minutes in Boot-PreSession Init-Phase)

Tags: boot, performance, windows-server, windows-server-2016

we are currently having problems with a Windows Server 2016 who takes approximate 20-30 minutes to boot. Most of the time the server is in the Boot Pre Session Init Phase and shows the following picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/silJG.png

I have already created a boot trace dump for the Windows Performance Analyzer with the command `xbootmgr -trace boot -traceflags dispatcher+latency`

I analyzed the dump, but I couldn't find a specific driver etc. which may cause the slow boot.

[image]

Do you guys have any idea?
Here is the link to the ETL-dump: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i2SRlEoHD_eyQ5cwYQmKFhLcQ51f7QOV/view?usp=sharing